# Hibernate search "join" on TextFullSearch

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I have 2 entities : Ad and Category;

I have a FullTextSearch (lucene) on Ad entity and I want to make a "join" beetween Ad And Category or to add somehow a where clause on Ad.category.id .

My Add class :

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "adds")
public class Ad implements Serializable {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="AdSQ", sequenceName="AdSQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AdSQ")
@Column(name = "id")
@JsonProperty("Id")
private Long __Id;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@IndexedEmbedded
@JoinColumn(name="idCategory", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_AD_CATEGORY"))
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
Category category; 

@Column(name = "price")
@JsonProperty("Price")
@Field
private Double _Price;
   ....
}
```

And Category :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories"/*, indexes = {@Index(columnList="id",name = "index_category")}*/)
public class Category implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CategorySQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CategorySQ", sequenceName="CategorySQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long __Id;
```

I used IndexedEmbedded on Ad and I think I should put @field on if field of category.

How should I make the link ?  I need to use a special type of query, analyzer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be aware that you choice to use non-standard property names (at least with respect to the JavaBeans conventions) may cause some trouble with Hibernate ORM and Hibernate Search, which might not detect the properties correctly. I'm not sure it will, but I'm just warning you: if it does not work, try renaming the properties.

Back to your question, you already made the link by adding an `@IndexedEmbedded`. If you only need the category ID in your search queries, you may simply use `@IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true, depth = 0)` without adding any field.
`depth = 0` is optional and will simply ensure that nothing except the category ID is embedded.

Then you will only have to add a clause to your query on `Ad`:

```
Query categoryQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onField( "category.__Id" ).matching( <some ID> ).createQuery()
Query booleanJunction = queryBuilder.bool()
    .must( categoryQuery )
    .must( <some other query> )
    .must( <some other query> )
    .createQuery()
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createQuery( booleanJunction, Ad.class );
```

If you want the name of the field to be different, you will have to add a `@DocumentId(name = "yourIdName")` annotation on the `__Id` field of the `Category` class. Then query like this:

```
Query categoryQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onField( "category.yourIdName" ).matching( <some ID> ).createQuery()
Query booleanJunction = queryBuilder.bool()
    .must( categoryQuery )
    .must( <some other query> )
    .must( <some other query> )
    .createQuery()
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createQuery( booleanJunction, Ad.class );
```